# How to explain this behavior of grep with a space?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm quite new in the Linux world and I wanted to use `grep` to find occurrences of `print` followed by a space. It appears in the file `/path/script.py` - you have to trust me here. I have been surprised to see that

```
grep --include=\script.py -rnwlF '/path/' -e 'print'
```

correctly outputs the file name, but

```
grep --include=\script.py -rnwlF '/path/' -e 'print '
```

does not. It is absolutely certain that the space exists in the file though.

What happens? Could it be some weird character encoding problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get that line from? By using the `-w` option, you ask `grep` to only select lines that match the whole word. So removing it should output the file, if it does contain "`print` followed by space":

```
grep --include=\script.py -rnlF '/path/' -e 'print '
```

However, if you are only `grep`'ing through one file, it would be simpler to just write:

```
grep -lF '/path/script.py' -e 'print '
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I copy-pasted the line from an example found on some web page, used it several times and it had never failed before. That's why I was rather thinking the problem was with the file.